# Start a program with argument using Powershell to get administrator privilege

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command, privileges, administrator

I have a .bat file like this. But I can not run the SeqEdit.exe as administrator by this command. I research about Powershell but I don't know how to use it correctly. please help me to convert this command to powershell command format.
Thank you in advance.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\National Instruments\TestStand 2016\Bin"
start /min "" SeqEdit.exe /runEntryPoint "Test UUTs" "C:\Peritec\111 Renesas for Oita\SLT Test System_ver109c\Sequence\SLT Test_Main_Ver2016.2.seq"

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Set-Location "C:\Program Files\National Instruments\TestStand 2016\Bin" 
Start-Process -FilePath ".\SeqEdit.exe" -ArgumentList "/runEntryPoint 'Test UUTs' 'C:\Peritec\111 Renesas for Oita\SLT Test System_ver109c\Sequence\SLT Test_Main_Ver2016.2.seq'" -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle minimized
```

If you want to do it with cmd first create this batch file:

```
@echo off
echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs 
echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs 
echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs 
cscript //nologo %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

Now run this from another batch file:

```
pushd "The location of seqedit.exe"
TheFullPathAndNameOfAboveBatchFile seqedit.exe "arguments" "arguments"
```

Comment: I would like to run from CMD. Please show me the equivalent command. Thank you.
It look likes:
powershell -command "....

Comment: I have included that method.

Comment: It's more complicated as I think before :(
I will try as your solution. thank you so much

Comment: So use the first method and if it works accept the answer / upvote it

Comment: I run the 1st solution from PowerShell windows, my program can not understand the command in ArgumentList

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath ".\SeqEdit.exe" -ArgumentList "/runEntryPoint `"Test UUTs`" `"C:\Peritec\9454 Renesas for Oita\SLT Test System_ver109c\Sequence\SLT Test_Main_Ver2016.2.seq`"" -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle minimized`
I use this one is OK

Comment: `powershell -command "Start-Process -FilePath ".\SeqEdit.exe" -ArgumentList '""/runEntryPoint Test UUTs C:\Peritec\111 Renesas for Oita\SLT Test System_ver109c\Sequence\SLT Test_Main_Ver2016.2.seq' -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle minimized`
I would like to user this one in command windows but I can not pass the double-quote "" out side of "Test UUTs" and "[the path]".
Please help me